# This code will get only first value from json string

Tags: java, android, json

please help me out from this i need to display the json array data but it will only show the first value from json .i tried to change the values but one value is shown not an array

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnadd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnhit);
    tvdata = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvJsonitem);
    btnadd.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new JSONTask().execute("https://api.myjson.com/bins/106o37");
                }
            }
    );

}
```

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask{

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);

            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(finalJson);

            StringBuffer finalBufferedData=new StringBuffer();
            for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String description = obj.getString("description");
                finalBufferedData.append(description + "\t\n"                             
                );
                return finalBufferedData.toString();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: put return finalBufferedData.toString(); outside for loop

Comment: How your json Looks like?

Comment: post your Json response

Comment: json responce is https://api.myjson.com/bins/106o37

Comment: put return finalBufferedData.toString(); outside for loop and check @MuhammadAdeel

Comment: Zaki Pathan thank you so much it works after putting return finalBufferedData.toString(); outside for loop.

Comment: Happy to help you brother :) :) :)

Answer (score -1):

Your return statement should be outside of your for loop. Now it is inside so the method returns the first value.

Comment: True. It was not visible when I started writing my answer. But what is your point?

Comment: you can't answer from comment

Comment: "you can't answer from comment" What does that even mean?

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
  @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);

        }

        String finalJson = buffer.toString();
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(finalJson);

        StringBuffer finalBufferedData=new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String description = obj.getString("description");
            finalBufferedData.append(description + "\t\n"                             
            );

        }

        return finalBufferedData.toString();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This answer is already given in comment for your kind information

Comment: @ZakiPathan where metioned in stackoverflow if one answer post two times then you have rights to  do minus mark.